# Zend Framework include path error in ubuntu

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have developed a Zend Framework application, which works well on xammp and windows. Now I want to transfer this application to a new ubuntu web server. However I get the following warning:

```
Warning: include_once(Zend/Navigation/Page/MVC.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146 Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Zend/Navigation/Page/MVC.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/application/../library/:/var/www/library:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/library/Zend/Loader.php on line 146 Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Navigation_Page_MVC' not found in /var/www/application/ext/views/NavigationCreator.php on line 34
```

So the Autoloader seems not to find the Zend library classes. My library is really at /var/www/library, my application at /var/www/application. I did sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www to rule out any permission issues.

I know that there are several related posts at SO, but non has helped me so far. Do you have any suggestions how to fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class name should be `Zend_Navigation_Page_Mvc` not `Zend_Navigation_Page_MVC` (note the difference in capitalization).

Whenever you move a project from windows system to a linux based one, these are common errors you might get. Because file names are case sensitives in linux. So, always check if the file exists and with the correct case.